# SQL Server DELETE OPENQUERY performance

Tags: sql-server, database-performance, openquery

We have a series of programs that are designed to move data from one SQL Server database into another using OPENQUERY and database linked servers.

We are noticing that queries such as the following are taking orders magnitude long than anticipated.

```
DELETE OPENQUERY(server, 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE pkf1 = ''v1'' AND pkf2 = ''v2''')
```

For example, if the above was rewritten as:

```
exec('DELETE * FROM table WHERE pkf1 = ''v1'' and pkf2 = ''v2''') at server
```

or

```
DELETE FROM server.schema.table WHERE pkf1 = 'v1' and pkf2 = 'v2'
```

the performance is only a few seconds compared to minutes using `OPENQUERY`.

Can someone explain why the `OPENQUERY` approach is so inefficient by comparison?  Does it not use the primary key indexes?

Comment: you can take a look here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/309182

Comment: " taking orders magnitude long than anticipated". Your anticipation is misguided. I guess the slow query transfers the records locally before deleting and the fast ones do not. OPENQUERY returns a resultset locally and the other methods do not. I wasn't familiar with the `at server` syntax though. Interesting. Surely that tells you that operations occur at the server not the client.

Answer (score 0):

Open query has a better handler than simple query like DELETE, and query is resolve within remote server